# How to make a virtual camera with python?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am experimenting with openCV in python and I made a simple webcam that will only show you in black and white but I was wondering if it was possible to somehow connect it to discord so whenever I call a friend he sees me in black and white.`

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 capture.set(3, 640)
 capture.set(4, 480)
 capture.set(10, 300)

 while True:
     sucess, img = capture.read()
     img = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 100)
     cv2.imshow("Webcam", img)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be late but check this out [pyvirtualcam](https://pypi.org/project/pyvirtualcam/)

install it first:

```
pip install pyvirtualcam
```

You can make it like this:

```
import pyvirtualcam
import numpy as np

with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=30) as cam:
    while True:
        frame = np.zeros((cam.height, cam.width, 4), np.uint8) # RGBA
        frame[:,:,:3] = cam.frames_sent % 255 # grayscale animation
        frame[:,:,3] = 255
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
```

Comment: Does not work under Linux!

Comment: @HenryRuhs did you install v4l2loopback, as the project description suggests?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the earlier comment, `pyvirtualcam` should work, but it relies on an existing virtual camera software.
As for Jan 2024, supported software list consists of:
Windows: OBS, Unity Capture
macOS: OBS
Linux: v4l2loopback

Comment: But it does not work on macos 14, regardless of software: https://github.com/letmaik/pyvirtualcam/issues/111